# Failed to load pdf document chrome

Tags: php, curl

try to load the pdf in chrome and print but keep getting this failed to load pdf document

```
$s = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($t)); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$r = curl_exec($s); 
curl_close($s); 
e($r);
```

Comment: Hello there! We need a bit more info to help. What is the URL of the PDF you're trying to display? If you remove the `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` what do you see in the page? Can you see any warnings in the Log?

Comment: hi @AndreaOlivato thanks for help i just tried if removed header it show totally blank and no warning show

Comment: here re the example of the http://api.xxx.my/xx/print/xx!print.action

Comment: This doesn't help, as we can not check the URL if it works or not. Since you mention that the page is blank if you remove the header, it means that your `curl` http request fails. Either you're calling the wrong URL with the wrong POST fields, or the website is blocking your request.